# Python Pandas agg error

Tags: pandas, aggregation, python-3.x

I am trying to generate descriptive statistics using agg function in Pandas.  I am having trouble with one line with a lambda function.  They work when I run them as separate lines of code, but when I put them as a single line I get errors.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

The following two lines of codes work when I run them individually.

First line of code:

```
bh_df.groupby('CAT.MEDV').agg(
  avg_Nox=('NOX', 'mean'))
```

Second line with lambda function.

```
bh_df.groupby('CAT.MEDV').agg(
   rng=("NOX", lambda x: (max(x) - min(x))))
```

However, when I combine them into a single line of code as:

```
bh_df.groupby('CAT.MEDV').agg(
   avg_Nox=('NOX', 'mean'),
   rng=("NOX", lambda x: (max(x) - min(x))))
```

I get a whole bunch of errors:

> File "", line 4, in
>
> rng=("NOX", lambda x: (max(x) - min(x))))
>
> File "C:\Users\pdile\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 1455, in aggregate
>       return super().aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\pdile\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 264, in aggregate
>       result = result[order]
>
> File "C:\Users\pdile\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2986, in **getitem**
>       indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)
>
> File "C:\Users\pdile\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1285, in _convert_to_indexer
>       return self._get_listlike_indexer(obj, axis, **kwargs)[1]
>
> File "C:\Users\pdile\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1092, in _get_listlike_indexer
>       keyarr, indexer, o._get_axis_number(axis), raise_missing=raise_missing
>
> File "C:\Users\pdile\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1185, in _validate_read_indexer

Final error:

> raise KeyError("{} not in index".format(not_found))
>
> KeyError: "[('NOX', '')] not in index"

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30718522/3409734). This may help. `bh_df.groupby('CAT.MEDV').agg([
   avg_Nox=('NOX', 'mean'),
   rng=("NOX", lambda x: (max(x) - min(x)))])`

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken the dataset used is the Boston home values dataset from http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/boston

The given code works fine on google colab if the dataset used is correct.
Please check the dataset before proceeding further.
Here are the screenshots for the same.

Step 1: Reading the dataset

[image]

Step 2: Printing the first 5 rows of the dataset
[image]

Step 3: Generating descriptive statistics using agg function in Pandas
Note: I changed the column names according to the dataset

[image]

Here is another solution for step 3
[image]

Note: I have run the script on google colab. Your problem might be there due to version issues.

Here is the code used.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
house=pd.read_csv('Boston.csv')
house.columns
 
house.groupby('medv').agg(
  avg_Nox=('nox', 'mean'),
  rng=("nox", lambda x: (max(x) - min(x))))
 
house.groupby(['medv'])['nox'].agg(
    [('avg_nox',  np.mean), 
    ('rng', lambda x: (max(x)-min(x)))])
```

You can view a similar machine learning project which predicts the price of the house based on other variable here https://bit.ly/3ApVCAO

Answer (score 0):

**Because there is no more column "NOX"**

you changed it in the previous mean aggregation. Try "avg_Nox" or whatever column  name you get after applying your first aggregation function

> ```
> bh_df.groupby('CAT.MEDV').agg(
>   avg_Nox=('NOX', 'mean'))
> ```

Comment: Sorry, that's not the issue, avg_Nox is only a label, that does not change the name of column. If I add a simple agg function instead of the lambda function the code runs fine. For example: bh_df.groupby('CAT.MEDV').agg( avg_Nox=('NOX', 'mean'), min_Nox=('NOX', min)) works fine.